# Going to UK from US on Tier 4 visa, but going on holiday from UK to Sardinia first

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, us-citizens

I am hoping my plan is OK.  I am a US citizen going to England on September 1st on a Tier 4 visa for two years.  I have had a trip to Sardinia planned for some time.

Are there any issues with my flying with my friend to London where I will enter under my Tier 4 visa instead as a visitor, staying three days for holiday, then flying to Sardinia on holiday before I start school?

I come back to England on the 13th of September.

I'm not going to have an issue going to/coming back from Sardinia with the new visa in my passport?

I am able to take quick holidays outside of England while I am on a UK Tier 4 visa, correct?

Comment: That's fine as long as your T4 is valid when you arrive.  You may be overthinking this.

Comment: Thank you.  Why do some sites say I would need a Schengen Visa to travel in Europe on the Tier 4?  I'm sure I'm overthinking but this potentially ruins a 4 girl holiday that's been planned for years before I decided to go back to school.

Comment: @GayotFow As a U.S. citizen he can enter/exit Schengen zone as a visitor, independent of his UK status, no?

Comment: Some sites are not set up for Americans and so they say that people need Schengen visas. Americans do not need one.  Ignore those sites and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

At your first time arrival to UK with tier 4 visa, you have to fill an extra form plus some proof related to your study, like school letter and letter of accommodation in UK. I see the procedure in major UK airport such as Heathrow (and there is a extra queue for those guys), but I do not know if it happens in minor airports or land/sea ports. You just have to fill the form on 1st arrival.

Every time arriving to UK within tier 4 visa period, the immigration staff always ask for some details related to  your study, like where do you study/what is your major?

But when you arrive to UK in normal (school) term periods, the staff generally ask for more details related to your trip, like does your school permit the trip/ who funds the trip/ why do you leave UK. Just reply honestly and don't lie, they will let you pass then.

They seldom ask for details when leaving UK.